# Multimap vs Multivalue Map - Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, multimap

What is difference between using MultiMap and Map of Collection?

Or, in other words, how multimap works in hazelcast? This may help to answer question on the trade-off of using one vs other.

PS: I understand the difference between Map and MultiMap. Question is difference between Multimap and Map of Collection.

Answer (score 2):

A map of collections is not a good idea in hazelcast.
Since you actually have a proxy to the actual map, modifying a collection from the "values" of this map will not reflect in the other proxies of the map.

Using a map of collections will require you to mange locking and concurrency between different threads updating the proxy map.

This will require you to use the following flow:

```
"lock" -> "get" -> update the value -> "unlock" methods of the IMap interface locking the key of the collection you wish to update.
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a `Multimap` refers to that a every input is associated with at least one output. On the contrary, a `Map` has a value that correspond just to ONE of the other value.

Multimap:

[image: Multimap]

Map of Collection

[image]

Check the multivalued function in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not answer, which one (Multimap, Map if List) is better and why?

Comment: It's not that one is better than the other, they have different uses. If you want to associate a unique key with a unique value, like a dictionary, go for the Map of List. If you want to associate a key with multple values (would be a set of values), go for the Multimap and have more than one value for a key.